# How do I get Vim to highlight YAML mapping key when it contains a space?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, yaml

I'm using Vim 7.3 on Ubuntu linux.

When I'm editing a YAML file

```
This:
    fnordy fnord: fnord
    fnords: super fnord
```

"fnords" would be colorized, but "fnordy fnords" would not be.

[image: fnords then fnordy fnord]

[image: fnordy fnord then fnord]

How can I fix this? I'm looking at my `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/yaml.vim` file, but I don't understand it enough to fix this.

### UPDATE

```
:color 
slate

:echo &ft
yaml
```

On `fnord: fnordy` (at the beginning of the line): yamlBlockMappingKey

On `fnordy fnord: fnord` (at the beginning of the line): yamlPlainScalar

Comment: How do you expect the syntax highlighting: Do you consider quotes to be valid characters for keys in associative arrays?

Comment: Have you contacted the syntax script's author (his address can be found in the script's header)?! He's probably best suited to explain the limitations and implement a fix.

Comment: @steffen, My bad - it was actually the space that I'm having problems with. I thought I had tried running that example through pyyaml, but apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of steffen's help, I compared both of the parsing commands.

The current script looks like this:

```
execute 'syn match yamlBlockMappingKey /^\s*\zs'.s:ns_plain_out.'\ze\s*:\%(\s\|$\)/ '.
            \'nextgroup=yamlKeyValueDelimiter'
```

The problem, specifically, is the `s:ns_plain_out`, which is a **non-space** pattern

So I changed the pattern to simply match on **any** character:

```
execute 'syn match yamlBlockMappingKey /^\s*\zs.*\ze\s*:\%(\s\|$\)/ '.
```

Which fixes this particular issue.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for this. By the way, you might want to delete the `.` at the end of your code block.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [YAML specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), spaces are valid characters in keys of mappings. Have a look at 3.2.1.1 in the specification and at [this example](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760372).

I'd say that the highlighting is correct. You have an unmeant linebreak in your first value using quotes (like in [this example](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761268)).

Comment: Apparently my newness with YAML is confusing my issue. Spaces in keys? Vim's syntax highlighting thinks that's not a real key. Period. With or without values (correct or incorrect). I've updated my example with (I hope!) YAML that is "clean".

Comment: No, in fact vim's syntax highlighting does not show that it is not a valid key. The 'no' is highlighted for being a special word possibly indicating a boolean value. So in my opinion there's nothing to fix in yaml.vim.

Comment: Here, all three keys (four words) are highlighted (This, fnordy fnord, fnords) on both Debian and Windows in both vim and gvim...

Comment: Added screenshot to my question.

Comment: There's something before line 85 leading to this highlighting. Post a smaller yaml excerpt in some pastebin. Also try exchanging line 85 and 86.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pupYRSXe and http://pastebin.com/GfSytMtg - adding some screenshots, too.

Comment: Could you move the cursor onto each line and show the results of ```:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")``` . Then please also show the results of ```:color``` and ```:echo &ft```.

Comment: Alright, my yaml.vim version is 2010-08-12, yours is 2010-10-08. You should contact the maintainer and ask. Use the older one meanwhile. You can find it here: http://ex-vim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/vim/runtime/syntax/yaml.vim

Answer (score 1):

Building on the accepted answer, here's what I put in my .vimrc to get this fix without editing any core vim files:

```
autocmd FileType yaml execute
      \'syn match yamlBlockMappingKey /^\s*\zs.*\ze\s*:\%(\s\|$\)/'
```