# Why isn't this Vim syntax command in after/ftplugin/yaml.vim working?

Tags: vim

I have the following line in `after/ftplugin/yaml.vim`

```
syn match yamlBlockMappingKey /^\s*\zs.*\ze\s*:\%(\s\|$\)/
```

I have also tried this:

```
execute 'syn match yamlBlockMappingKey /^\s*\zs.*\ze\s*:\%(\s\|$\)/'
```

The purpose of this is to make vim properly highlight keys that contain spaces, as per [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456538/how-do-i-get-vim-to-highlight-yaml-mapping-key-when-it-contains-a-space).  The problem is that the command doesn't seem to work when I open a new YAML file.  I know that `after/ftplugin/yaml.vim` is being sourced, as I put an `echom` command in there and it shows up in `messages`.  Also, if I just take the line and paste it into the command prompt and execute it, it works.  Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ftplugin` scripts are sourced *before* the syntax scripts, so the default YAML syntax clears your additional definition. Place your extension into `after/syntax/yaml.vim` instead; after all, you're extending a syntax, not filetype settings.

Comment: I want to change html syntax to php, so I create ~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim, and put `setlocal syntax=php` in it, but does not work. How can i do this.

Comment: @Sam Redefine the filetype detection from HTML to PHP. If you don't know how, read the help of ask a separate question here.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I konw redefine filetype, I thought that the syntax can be modified individually, thanks.